# Possible to include Parameter in the Push Notification from C2MD?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have installed Push Notification in the Android Mobile Phones using C2MD Server.
Now i just to know enhance that one i.e. When push notification occurs then it should be notified through the Preloaded voice in the server.
Whether the voice data is send as a parameter to the Mobile or any other parameter is passed from C2MD Server to the device.
Please Help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send push to device you can send any key-value pair, so I suppose you can send bytes of any sound. But there is [limits](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#limitations) for c2dm messages - it can be maximum 1024 bytes. So you can provide only very short sound.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the sound or anything via C2DM is not feasible at all.C2DM is for sending any announcement, not for sending data. there are millions of pushes occurs on a same time, when u pushing the file, using key-value pair for retrieving sound bytes, there is limitation on C2DM of 1KB, you can handle a message which will appropriately play sound file from assets, it will be more feasible.. and right way to do it. Like getting a value '1', it will play another file, and value '2' will play another file, i think that's simple or making dynamic you can pass the sound-file URL. and you can play any bigger sound file then...